# NLP - Best document embedding library

Tags: nlp, document, gensim, embedding, bert-language-model

Good day, fellow humans (?).

I have a methodological question that is confused by a deep research in a tiny amount of time.

The question arises from the following problem(s): I need to apply semi-supervised or unsupervised clustering on documents. I have ~300 documents classified with multi-labels and approximately 3400 documents not classified. The number of unsupervised documents could become ~10'000 in the next days.

The main idea is that of applying semi-supervised clustering based on the labels at hands. Alternatively, that of going fully unsupervised for soft clustering.

We thought of creating embeddings for the whole documents, but here lies the confusion: which library is the best for such a task?

I guess the utmost importance needs to lie in the context of the whole document. As far as I know, BERT and FastText provide context-dependent word embedding, but not whole document embedding. On the other hand, Gensim's Doc2Vec is context-agnostic, right?

I think I saw a way to train sentence embeddings with BERT, via the HuggingFace API, and was wondering whether it could be useful to consider the whole document as a single sentence.

Do you have any suggestion? I'm probably exposing my utter ignorance and confusion on the matter, but my brain is melted.

Thank you very much for your time.

Viva!

Edit to answer to @gojomo:

My documents are on average ~180 words. The original task was that of multi-label text classification, i.e. each document can have from 1 to N labels, with the number of labels now being N=18.  They are highly imbalanced.
Having only 330 labeled documents so far due to several issues, we asked the documents' provider to give also unlabeled data, that should reach the order of the 10k.
I used FastText classification mode, but the result is obviously atrocious. I also run a K-NN with Doc2Vec document embedding, but the result is obviously still atrocious.
I was going to use biomedical BERT-based models (like BioBERT and SciBERT) to produce a NER tagging (trained on domain-specific datasets) on the documents to later apply a classifier.
Now that we have unlabeled documents at disposal, we wanted to adventure into semi-supervised classification or unsupervised clustering, just to explore possibilities. I have to say that this is just a master thesis.

Comment: More of a remark than an actual answer, but it's worth knowing that sentence embedding methods (SBERT, InferSent, FastText) often work better for shorter amounts of text (for actual real sentences) and tend to see their performance decrease for longer amounts of text (ie. for multiple sentences put together). So I would personally probably go for something like averaging or TF-IDFing the word embeddings of each whole document...

No idea as to what would come from training BERT on whole documents using the HuggingFace API though so maybe it'd work?

Comment: @Tibbles : Thanks for your answer, it's actually very informative. By averaging the TF-IDF of word embedding, you mean the bag-of-words style embedding? I know that Gensim also supports doc2bow for later TF-IDF measures.

Comment: Well, I don't know if we're saying the same thing but I meant using TF-IDF as a weighting factor for averaging the word embeddings over the entire corpus. That is, using this weighting factor after having embedded the words (which can be done with many different word embedding libraries - you mentionned BERT and FastText for instance).

Comment: What do you mean by "context of the whole document" – what other context would there be? And what do you mean by "context-agnostic" for `Doc2Vec` (aka 'Paragraph Vectors')? Also, how long are your documents, & how large is the set of known labels, & how many labels per document? (Are you trying to discover new not-yet-used labels via the clustering?) Note FastText has a 'classification mode' which specifically trains per-word-vectors to be better when summed to predict known labels. Ultimately, I doubt there's a one "best" approach – testing against your data & exact goals may surprise.

Comment: BERT has a max I put size, so you probably won’t be able to embed entire documents without truncating them. I find Universal Sentence Encoder easier to use for document embedding, also by google. My current approach is to break down the document into sentences and paragraphs and store those relations in a db, and also store document, paragraph, and sentence embeddings

Comment: @jogomo I edited the original post to answer. :)

Comment: For  others who didn't know what TF-IDF was: "term frequency–inverse document frequency, is a numerical statistic that is intended to reflect how important a word is to a document in a collection or corpus.[1] It is often used as a weighting factor in searches of information retrieval, text mining, and user modeling. The tf–idf value increases proportionally to the number of times a word appears in the document and is offset by the number of documents in the corpus that contain the word, which helps to adjust for the fact that some words appear more frequently in general." From wikipedia.